# Merge Multiple text file, condition to merge files of created today

Tags: powershell

I want to merge multiple text files from a folder, but condition to merge the text file is today's created text files only to be merged. I do have other date created files in the folder, to exclude all those files.

This codes do merge and create a single text file.
$yourdir="c:\temp\"

```
gci $yourdir -File -Filter *.txt | gc | out-file -FilePath "C:\Temp\old\totalresult.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe the result from the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to the `Where-Object` cmdlet and filter them:

```
Get-ChildItem  $yourdir -File -Filter *.txt  | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq ((get-date).Date) } | 
    Get-Content | 
    Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\old\totalresult.txt"
```